# Entity Framework, Make object loaded with SQLQuery state change to modified after modify some property value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I use DBContext.Database.SqlQuery("Select * FROM Table"); to load object, loaded object state in DBContext.ChangeTracker.Entries() always remain unchanged even I modified some property..
I try to change it manually with DBContext.Entry(Object).State = State.Modified, but it throw error instead..

I need to load with raw SqlQuery because i need to lock the table after select, for AutoNumbering use..

```
    public double GetAutoNo(eVoucherContext context, string lookUpValue, int requiredNumber)
    {
        AutoNumberDetail autoNumberDetail =  context.Database.SqlQuery<AutoNumberDetail>("SELECT * FROM AutoNumberDetails WITH (HOLDLOCK XLOCK ROWLOCK) WHERE AutoNumberId = '" + Id.ToString() + "' AND LookUpValue = '" + lookUpValue + "'").FirstOrDefault();
        if (autoNumberDetail == null)
        {
            autoNumberDetail = new AutoNumberDetail();
            autoNumberDetail.AutoNumberId = Id;
            autoNumberDetail.LookUpValue = lookUpValue;
            autoNumberDetail.LastNumber = 0;
            context.AutoNumberDetails.Add(autoNumberDetail);
        }
        double currentNumber = autoNumberDetail.LastNumber + 1;
        autoNumberDetail.LastNumber += requiredNumber; //I Need it to track that the LastNumber already changed, so when I call saveChanges on context, it can update my LastNumber
        return currentNumber;
    }
```

> 

**Updated:**
Got the solution already, use DbContext.AutoNumberDetails.SqlQuery instead

Comment: EF behaviour is correct here.  the entities loaded via Raw SQL are not tracked as your context is not aware of what you have loaded, hence cannot cache it to do change tracking. please can you specify what exactly are you trying to do and why do you need change tracking after that query

Comment: @PreetSingh i've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You could use AttachListEntries

```
    public void AttachListEntries<T>(List<T> entries) where T : class
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            var result = AttachToAndGetIfExists(entries[i]);
            if (result != null)
            {
                entries[i] = result;
            }
        }
    }

    public T AttachToAndGetIfExists<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;
        ObjectSet<T> objectSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        var key = objContext.CreateEntityKey(string.Format("{0}.{1}", objectSet.EntitySet.EntityContainer.Name, objectSet.EntitySet.Name), entity);
        ObjectStateEntry entry;

        if (objContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out entry))
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                objContext.AttachTo(key.EntitySetName, entry);
            }
            return (T)entry.Entity;
        }

        objContext.AttachTo(key.EntitySetName, entity);
        return null;
    }
```